# Adding days to getDate function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, datepicker

I have this function to select the date which works fine

```
formatDateField(event: Date, formControl: string) {
    this.form
      .get(formControl)
      .patchValue(
        this.datePipe.transform(event.getTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
      );
  }
```

I added a button to add the days to it using this code below but says undefined in developers tool > console:

```
  addDaysToDateForm(formName: string, days: number) {
    let formDate: Date = this.form.get(formName).value || new Date();
    formDate.setDate(formDate.getDate() + days);
    this.form.get(formName).setValue(formDate);
  }
  setTodayForm(formName: string) {
    this.form.get(formName).setValue(new Date());
  }
```

Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: I would advise to use a lib like `luxon` for that.

Comment: What does `this.form.get(formName).value` return? Does it really return a **`Date` object**? Your code seems to assume it does, but `value` in relation to DOM forms is a string. Of course, this may be some lib, but...

Comment: Fundamentally, if `formDate` is really a `Date` object and `days` is really a number, then `formDate.setDate(formDate.getDate() + days)` **will** add `days` days to the date. So if you're not seeing that, then one of those two things isn't correct (`formDate` isn't a `Date`, or `days` isn't a number).

Comment: I think `this.form.get(formName).value` returns a `string` instead of a `Date` object, so what @T.J.Crowder saying is true.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder formDate is a Date object. formName is a string. how do i convert string to date in this code using this.form.get(formName).value ...?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have [Typed Forms (just yet)](https://blog.angular.io/typed-forms-the-rfc-is-here-53263e792c89) so values returned from form values aren't typed (as @T.J.Crowder says in the comments). You can convert the value returned from `this.form.get(formName).value` to a date by calling `new Date()` on it. i.e. `new Date(this.form.get(formName).value)`

Comment: When suggesting using the built–in parser, it's also good to include a link to [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) :-)